# How can i populate drop down lists in mvc5 such that each list is dependent on the previous drop down list?

Tags: c#

How can i populate drop down lists in mvc5 such that each list is dependent on the previous drop down list? 
Example: 
Database stores information on cars first field drop down list should display all car manufacturers, depending on my selection the second field drop down list should only display data of car models for the brand i have selected.

Answer (score 1):

You should use js for dropdown 'change' event. Then at least two options are possible.
Ajax request for next drop down values (different libs like select2 could handle that scenario out of the box) or form posting to the action, which will render it back with the next dropdown values provided.